# Set startcoordinates for an java applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, coordinates, java-2d

How do I set the start coordinates for what my java applet is showing? I want it to start showing from 0,1000. I want this because all of my drawn elements is located around that coordinate.

```
public void init() {
    setSize(1000, 500);
    ...
}

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
   ...
    }
}
```

Currently its 500 high but my rectangles are drawn at 1000. I want it to start showing at 1000. Instead of being from 0-500 I want it to be 1000-1500.

Comment: You need to explain this a little more. it is not clear what you are asking. Maybe translate() method of the Graphics object?

Comment: Check my post. I've updated it

Answer (score 2):

You need to scale the drawing so that it fits on your screen area. If your drawing is 1000 pixels high and you want it to fit on a screen with maximum height of 500 pixels then divide all the dimensions of the drawing by 2 and the drawing will fit on the visible area. You may also want to take a look at the [translate method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#translate%28int,%20int%29) of the Graphics object and see if that helps.

You may want to override the paintComponents method rather than the paint method for drawing on a component.